# Android Past SMS Contacts/Numbers

Tags: android, mobile, sms, history, contacts

I know this has kinda been asked a million times but I wanted to filter in on a specific detail about a SMS message.

Does Google offer any access to SMS history, specifically the number of whom it's from. Don't need anything else.

Just want to know if I can launch my app and have access to SMS History Contacts/Numbers

[same iOS question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066878/ios-past-sms-contacts-numbers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Querying this Url: Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/canonical-addresses") you can find a list with all phone numbers you have ever communicated via SMS with.

It has only two columns - id and phone number.